# Is it possible to build this layout in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a custom widget called CustomCircle which have a center parameter used to display another widget. Is it possible to use this same widget to make something like this dynamically (the number of circles could change)?

[image]

CustomCircle (
radius: radius,
color: Colors.blue,
center: CustomCircle,
);

Comment: You can use Stack widget

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CustomPaint` or Stack widget to create this.  Here is a demo with Stack.

```dart
class AS3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const AS3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          final width = constraints.maxWidth;
          final numberOfCircle = 14;
          final initialCircleWidth = width / numberOfCircle;

          return Stack(
            children: [
              for (int i = numberOfCircle; i > 0; i--)
                Align(
                  child: Container(
                    width: initialCircleWidth * i,
                    height: initialCircleWidth * i,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: CircleBorder(), color: ([...Colors.primaries]..shuffle()).first),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

If you need an outline border, you wrap the Stack with another decoration(can be container's decoration)